# remove duplicates and find the largest element

Tags: java

list of integers with duplicates and integer N. Remove the duplicates from the list and find the N-th largest element in the modified list.

Implement at least two different solutions to find N-th largest element with O(N*log(N)) average time complexity in Big-O notation, where N is the number of elements in the list

The below is the solution i thought of is there any better way of implementing? Also, how do I implement two different solutions ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    int[] list= {5,3,8,2,5,7,6,7,3,7};
    int n = 3;

    System.out.println("Printing list before removing duplicates");
    for (int i : list) {
        System.out.println(i+" ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[i] < list[j]) {
                int swap = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j]=swap;
            }
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                    list[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Printing list after removing duplicates");
    for (int i : list) {
            System.out.println(i+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("the N-th largest element in the modified list is"+ list[n-1]);
}
```

Comment: If this code works, you want [codereview.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of problem really you need to look at what language tools are provided to you and how to make use of them to do the hard work for you.

To remove duplicates just place them into a `Set`. To have them sorted use a `TreeSet`.

So you get:

```
Set<Integer> values = new TreeSet<Integer>();
```

That will sort them from smallest to largest, to reverse the order specify your own comparator for the `TreeSet` that just reverses the natural ordering.

Then iterate over the `Set` and the nth value returned from the iterator is your value.

Your current code looks mostly valid, it doesn't actually remove duplicates though - you need to actually remove things from the Array for that, which Arrays do not support without recreating them as they cannot be resized. Additionally it will get confused if you include 0s or negative numbers. For example the biggest number in (-3, -5, -6, -6) will come back as 0.

Answer (score 0):

One line for each task if you start with a collection.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5,3,8,2,5,7,6,7,3,7));
```

To remove duplicates:

```
List<Integer> nodups = new ArrayList<Integer>(new HashSet<Integer>(list));
```

To find largest:

```
Integer largest = Collections.max(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless for some reason you're bound to using only primitives, Tim's answer solves the sorting problem. To implement multiple "solutions", just create two different functions which take the list of numbers and the value `n` as parameters:

```
public void firstSolution(int[] numbers, int n) {
// one implementation
}

public void secondSolution(int[] numbers, int n) {
// another implementation
}
```

Then simply make the appropriate function calls in `main`.